# Not getting display through VGA after bootup

Tags: display, monitor

I connect my Netbook to my TV through VGA, and it shows while at post and boot-loader screen, but once I'm booted then I get no picture. I checked my cable connection, and even swapped cables to make sure.

I use AMD Control Center for display, and it detects my display. It's just not showing up. I've never had this problem. *Is any one else having this issue?*

Answer (score 0):

try to enter ubuntu recovery in grub meneu. then repair broken package (remember to activate network) after that hit the resume in the menu. it solved my problems for a clean install of ubuntu 12.04 LTS-